# Connect AppMaker to Google SQL in Secure

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform, google-app-maker

Please tell me about secure setup of Cloud SQL with Google AppMaker.
In GCP, I created a second generation instance(My SQL).

In the following URL, to connect to Cloud SQL from AppMaker,
Cloud SQL side approves `appmaker-maestro@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` as Role.
https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql

In this case, since the above Role is common to all the applications created by Google App Maker, if someone knows the Database user name and password, it seems to be accessible from any AppMaker in the world.

How can I setup Cloud SQL so that can be accessed Cloud SQL only from specific AppMaker or from internal network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Maker do check the ACL(access control list) of the project when establishing the Cloud SQL connection, so if the user account doesn't have the right permission to the project, the connection will be denied, despite whether he/she has the username/password or not.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As you wrote, I could confirm that another appmaker with another Google acount cannot deploy.